# Images don't showing until I click the screen iOS

Tags: jquery, html, ios

I have to resolve an iOS bug where when the phone has no internet connection the images disappear.

The steps taken are the follows:

1. Open the app
2. Go to one of the options (for example, the one remarked in red)

   - [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5oEr.png)
3. Go back to the screen and images are gone (Only the text endured).

   - [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loNNo.png)

It's strange because when the device is under the "supervision" of the safari inspect, it works like magic.

I have the same code in other version of the app and this doesn't happen there. I compared the code and there's no difference at all!

Here's my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https: data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com * 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; media-src *">

    <title>MobileBanking.Pac</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

    <link href="css/font.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/fontOverrides.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/pickadate.js/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/pickadate.js/default.date.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <link href="css/Home/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <div class="background-blue background-blue-font" id="ActionButtonsIndex">
            <div data-role="header" class="ui-content-transparent">
                <h1><img src="images/logo.png" width="170"></h1>
            </div>
            <a href="Views/Authentication/AuthenticationStep0.html" class="db p20b login-btn">
                Ingresar a Movil
                <img src="images/right207.png" width="13">
            </a>
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <a href="Views/Selfadhesion/SelfadhesionStep1.html" class="ui-block-a bg-darker line-right">
                    <img src="images/icon_autoadhesion.png" width="33">
                    <p>Regístrate</p>
                </a>
                <a id="geolocation" class="ui-block-b bg-darker line-right" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0;">
                    <img src="images/icon_sucursales.png" width="33">
                    <p>Agencias y Cajeros</p>
                </a>
                <a id="promo" class="ui-block-c bg-darker">
                    <img src="images/icon_promociones.png" width="33">
                    <p>Promociones</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <a href="Views/Home/HomeStep1.html" class="bg-darker line-top">
                <img src="images/ic_call_white_48dp.png" width="20">
                Contacto
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-loaded">
            <img src="images/inicio_banner_default2.jpg" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
        <a id="btnShare" href="#" class="background-blue p15v" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <img src="images/ic_thumb_up_white_48dp.png" width="20">
            Compartir
        </a>
    </div>


    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <!--<script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.validate.addMethod.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/configuration.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Connection.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Context.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Resources.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ViewConector.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.dateFormat-1.0.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="scripts/imgcache.js"></script>-->
    <!--pickadate.js scripts-->
    <script src="scripts/pickadate.js/picker.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/pickadate.js/picker.date.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/pickadate.js/picker.time.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/pickadate.js/es_ES.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/xml2json.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Helpers.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

    <!--adding by CGV-->
    <script src="scripts/external/underscore.js"></script>

    <!--adding by JP-->
    <script src="scripts/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no way to help you unless you post code

Comment: Please write down your code for both the pages. I think your code has some issue regarding showing images

Comment: @random now my code is posted!

Comment: @nikunj-acharya now my code is posted!

Answer (score 0):

you will use web+cache for image.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/SDWebImage

[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePictureUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];